# How to fire a function in child from parent in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React app has three components. Two of them are child components and the other is parent. I need to pass a data (projectId) from one child component to the other child through the parent component and after receiving the data, fire a function. As my example, I'm sending projectId from ChildOne to Parent and then send projectId from Parent to ChildTwo. ChildTwo has a function called setProject(projectId) and I need to fire it once the projectID is received. **The problem is I can't get the function getProjectId fired in ChildTwo by clicking on the button in ChildOne. I also tried with componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps which are not working for me.** How can I do this?

Here what I tried

ChildOne :

```
class ChildOne extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          projectId: 3,
        };
    }

    sendProjectId = (projectId) => {
       this.props.sendId(projectId)
    }

    render() {
       return(
         <button onClick={() => this.sendProjectId(this.state.projectId)}>
            Click
         </button>
       )
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          projectId: '',
        };
    }

    getId = (proId) => {
       this.setState({
          projectId : proId
       })
    }

    render() {
       return(
         <div>
           <CildOne sendId={this.getId} />

           <CildTwo sendOneId={this.state.projectId} />
         </div>
       )
    }
}
```

ChildTwo:

```
class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          projectId: '',
        };
    }

    getProjectId = (this.props.sendOneId) => {
       //Do something with this.props.sendOneId
    }

    render() {
       return(
         <div></div>
       )
    }
}
```

Comment: What you intend to do with `this.props.sendOneId` in ChildTwo ? The solution will depend on your usecase

Comment: I think `componentWillReceiveProps` should work fine in your scenario.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would depend on what `ChildTwo` wants to accomplish with the said data.

**Case 1:**

`ChildTwo` intends to fetch some data with the corresponding `projectId` and display it in the component. Then, you can easily fetch this data in the parent component and pass the data down as `props`.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          projectId: '',
          dataForChildTwo: null,
        };
    }

    getId = (proId) => {
       this.setState({
          projectId : proId,
          dataForChildTwo: fetchData(proId)
       })
    }

    render() {
       return(
         <div>
           <CildOne sendId={this.getId} />

           <CildTwo data={this.state.dataForChildTwo} />
         </div>
       )
    }
}
```

**Case 2:**

`ChildTwo` intends to make some change to something inside it when `projectId` changes. Then you can use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) hook to see if prop changed and respond to it.

```
class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          projectId: '',
        };
    }

    getProjectId = (this.props.sendOneId) => {
       //Do something with this.props.sendOneId
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      if(this.props.projectId!==prevProps.projectId) {
        // do something
      }
    }

    render() {
       return(
         <div></div>
       )
    }
}
```

**Case 3**:

If none of the above cases work for you, then you can manually reload the complete component when the `projectId` changes using a `key` attribute:

```
<CildTwo key={this.state.projectId} sendOneId={this.state.projectId} />
```

Note: This reloads the whole component quite unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you! your **Case 3** answer solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Our you can try a functional component or hooks if you want to set some state

```
function ChildOne(props) {
  const [projectId, setProjectId] = useState(3);
  function sendProjectId(data){
       props.sendId(projectId)
    }
   return(
         <button onClick={() => sendProjectId(projectId)}>
            Click
         </button>
       )
}



function ChildTwo(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('')
  function getProjectId(data) {
       //Do something with this.props.sendOneId
       console.log(`data here ${data}`)
       return false;
    }
    getProjectId(props.sendOneId)
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )
}


function Parent(){
   const [projectId, setProjectId] = useState('');
   function getId(proId) {
     setProjectId(proId)
   }
   return(
         <div>
           <ChildOne sendId={getId} />

           <ChildTwo sendOneId={projectId} />
         </div>
       )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a mistake in `getProjectId` function of `ChildTwo` component.

Your function cannot receive anything as a parameter from prop.

So, your function should look like:

```
getProjectId = (sendOneId) => {
   //Do something with this.props.sendOneId
}
```

Then you should use `componentWillReceiveProps` like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.sendOneId !== nextProps.sendOneId) {
    this.getProjectId(nextProps.sendOneId);
  }
}
```

Here is a working codesandbox example that I created to fix your problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/5v4rn7qnll

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and [will cease working in v17](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

Comment: @Andy I know that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated. But OP mentioned that he tried `componentWillReceiveProps` and was not successful. That means he is safe to use it for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) with a condition to check to see whether the projectId in `state` needs to be updated when `sendOneId` changes. You can then use `setState`s callback to call `getProjectId`:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  const { projectId: currentProjectId } = this.state;
  const { sendOneId: projectId } = this.props;
  if (projectId !== currentProjectId) {
    this.setState({ projectId }, () => this.getProjectId());
  }
}
```

Full working example:

```js
class ChildOne extends React.Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        projectId: 3,
      };
    }

    sendProjectId = (projectId) => {
      this.props.sendId(projectId)
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <button onClick={() => this.sendProjectId(this.state.projectId)}>
          Click
        </button>
      );
    }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      projectId: '',
    };
  }

  getId = (projectId) => {
    this.setState({ projectId });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildOne sendId={this.getId} />
        <ChildTwo sendOneId={this.state.projectId} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

class ChildTwo extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        projectId: '',
      };
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
      const { projectId: currentProjectId } = this.state;
      const { sendOneId: projectId } = this.props;
      if (projectId !== currentProjectId) {
        this.setState({ projectId }, () => this.getProjectId());
      }
    }

    getProjectId = () => {
      console.log(this.state.projectId);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div></div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```